# Getting multiple custom field with same name using Custom Field Tooling API

Tags: custom-field, tooling-api

I am facing a scenario where I am getting multiple custom fields with same name when executing tooling api for Custom Field

The API I am using is : `/services/data/v55.0/tooling/query?q=Select+DeveloperName,Id,ManageableState,NamespacePrefix,TableEnumOrId+from+CustomField+Where+TableEnumOrId='Account'`

The response I am getting is:

```
[
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EPllEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EPllEAG",
    "ManageableState": "unmanaged",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EPlnEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EPlnEAG",
    "ManageableState": "unmanaged",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EPlkEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EPlkEAG",
    "ManageableState": "unmanaged",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EPlmEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EPlmEAG",
    "ManageableState": "unmanaged",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EPlqEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EPlqEAG",
    "ManageableState": "unmanaged",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EPlpEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EPlpEAG",
    "ManageableState": "unmanaged",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EPloEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EPloEAG",
    "ManageableState": "unmanaged",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EVw6EAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EVw6EAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EVw7EAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EVw7EAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EVw8EAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EVw8EAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EVw9EAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EVw9EAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EVwAEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EVwAEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EVwBEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EVwBEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EVwCEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EVwCEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EVwDEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EVwDEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EVwEEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EVwEEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EVwFEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EVwFEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EVwGEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EVwGEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EVwHEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EVwHEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EVwIEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EVwIEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EVwJEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EVwJEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EVwKEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EVwKEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EVwLEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EVwLEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003EVwMEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003EVwMEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7QEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7QEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7REAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7REAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7SEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7SEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7TEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7TEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7UEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7UEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7VEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7VEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7WEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7WEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7XEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7XEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7YEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7YEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7ZEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7ZEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7aEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7aEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7bEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7bEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7cEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7cEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7dEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7dEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7eEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7eEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7fEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7fEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7gEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7gEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7hEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7hEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7iEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7iEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7jEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7jEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7kEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7kEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7lEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7lEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7mEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7mEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7nEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7nEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7oEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7oEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7pEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7pEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7qEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7qEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7rEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7rEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7sEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7sEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7tEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7tEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7uEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7uEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7vEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7vEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7wEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7wEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7xEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7xEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7yEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7yEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS7zEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS7zEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS80EAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS80EAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS81EAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS81EAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS82EAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS82EAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS83EAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS83EAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS84EAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS84EAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS85EAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS85EAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS86EAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS86EAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS87EAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS87EAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS88EAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS88EAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS89EAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS89EAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GS8AEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GS8AEAW",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GTnfEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GTnfEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000003GTngEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000003GTngEAG",
    "ManageableState": "installed",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000005Au44EAC"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000005Au44EAC",
    "ManageableState": "unmanaged",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000005Au49EAC"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000005Au49EAC",
    "ManageableState": "unmanaged",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000006JDyDEAW"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000006JDyDEAW",
    "ManageableState": "unmanaged",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000006JDyiEAG"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000006JDyiEAG",
    "ManageableState": "unmanaged",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f00000F0piWEAR"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f00000F0piWEAR",
    "ManageableState": "unmanaged",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f0000073t76EAA"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f0000073t76EAA",
    "ManageableState": "unmanaged",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000007lGjYEAU"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000007lGjYEAU",
    "ManageableState": "unmanaged",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000007lf51EAA"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000007lf51EAA",
    "ManageableState": "unmanaged",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000007lf5wEAA"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000007lf5wEAA",
    "ManageableState": "unmanaged",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000007llLHEAY"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000007llLHEAY",
    "ManageableState": "unmanaged",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000007llShEAI"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000007llShEAI",
    "ManageableState": "unmanaged",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f000007lnuhEAA"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f000007lnuhEAA",
    "ManageableState": "unmanaged",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f00000GLXiTEAX"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f00000GLXiTEAX",
    "ManageableState": "unmanaged",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f00000KkkEXEAZ"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f00000KkkEXEAZ",
    "ManageableState": "unmanaged",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f00000UDKT9EAP"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f00000UDKT9EAP",
    "ManageableState": "unmanaged",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "CustomField",
      "url": "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5f00000h7aXNEAY"
    },
    "DeveloperName": "Active",
    "Id": "00N5f00000h7aXNEAY",
    "ManageableState": "installedEditable",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Account"
  }
]
```

I need to get the ID of the custom field named Active__c in the Account object and there is only one field with the name Active__c, but CustomField Tooling API is giving multiple fields with the same name in Object Account.

Is there a way to filter them out and select the actual one?

Comment: Can you check if there are any deleted fields(erased recently?) with the name Active__c? 

I created a dummy customfield on account object and deleted it but the query `/services/data/v55.0/tooling/query?q=Select+DeveloperName,Id,ManageableState,NamespacePrefix,TableEnumOrId+from+CustomField+Where+TableEnumOrId='Account'` still includes it in the resuts.

[Physical delete](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000336818&type=1) would be the solution in such a scenario. Thanks